# MySQL - select all rows which user doesn't own

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm having a small MySQL problem. I want to select all rows of my table which contain data that the user doesn't own (it's an exchange tool).

Example:

```
id  |  owner  |  event
----------------------
1   |    4    |    3
2   |    5    |    3
3   |    3    |    2
4   |    5    |    6
```

I'm owner #4. I want to see all events except the ones I already own, so I want to get a result like:

```
event |  offered by
-------------------
2     |     3
6     |     5
```

Is is possible to select this via SQL or do I have to select all the users own events and remove all other events with the same `id` from the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.event, a.owner AS `Offered By`
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   a.event NOT IN
        (
            SELECT  b.event
            FROM    TableName b
            WHERE   owner = 4
        )
```

or by using `JOIN` which I preferred more,

```
SELECT  a.event, a.owner AS `Offered By`
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN tableName b
            ON  a.event = b.event AND
                b.owner = 4
WHERE   b.event IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2be85/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════╦════════════╗
║ EVENT ║ OFFERED BY ║
╠═══════╬════════════╣
║     2 ║          3 ║
║     6 ║          5 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: I actually prefer your first version, because my actual statement is a little bit more extensive than my shown example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT event, offered_by FROM events_table WHERE owner <> 4
```

or if they are 2 table for example `events` and `offers`

```
SELECT tb1.event, tb1.offered by FROM offers as tb1
INNER JOIN events as tb2 on tb1.event = tb2.event
WHERE tb2.owner <> 4
```

Comment: No, as you seen, there are two owners to one event, and he didn't want to include it in result returned.

Comment: your query will not give correct results. the second one will list all results from the table

Comment: Yeah, I voted for the answer above - LEFT JOIN with NULL event is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just assuming php here

```
SELECT event
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
WHERE owner NOT IN '$owner_id'
```